# Privileges required to change Mac network settings programmatically, as normal user

Tags: c, macos, networking

Is there a special group or a capability (similar to Linux' CAP_NET_xxx) that would enable a user to change network settings programmatically on Mac OS X? The settings I am interested in are the IP address and netmask of an interface, set programmatically from a C program (via an ioctl call, sending an ifreq struct). The user type I am using at the moment is a stock "Admin" account on my Mac laptop. Ultimately, I wish for my program to add the user once to such a convenient group so that in subsequent runs the user can manipulate the IP address of interfaces without prompting.

Thanks

Comment: Why the down vote? A bit of feed-back would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X will pretty much require `root` privileges to change any network settings. You would need to run the program as `root` in order to change the settings. As mentioned by @edufinn, the `sudo` command is ideal for this.

However, if you want to change the configuration in a supported manner you should try one of the following approaches:

- Script the [`scutil` command](http://www.afp548.com/2005/07/17/using-scutil-to-set-dns-server/).
- use the [Dynamic Store API](http://00f.net/2011/08/14/programmatically-changing-network-configuration-on-osx/), which is part of the [SystemConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/SysConfig/_index.html) Framework.
- use the [`networksetup`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html) command, which allows easy getting/setting of values.

Changing the configuration through these APIs will inform applications that the network configuration has changed so they can react appropriately - e.g. make/reset a connection.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X is BSD system. You can run your program with `sudo` command. It's not very obvious from your post what is exactly a problem?